# a python script fails to import kafka library while running inside docker

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka

I have the following python script that pulls tweets from twitter and sends it to a kafka topic. The script runs perfectly, but when I try to run it inside a docker container, it fails to import the kafka library. It says "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

Following is content of the python script(twitter_app.py):

```
import socket
import sys
import requests
import requests_oauthlib
import json
import kafka
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import time
from kafka import SimpleProducer
from kafka import KafkaClient

###################################################
# My own twitter access tokens
####################################################
ACCESS_TOKEN = '28778811-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'HBGjTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CONSUMER_KEY = '#################################'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '############################################'

my_auth = requests_oauthlib.OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)

####################################################
# Kafka Producer
####################################################
twitter_topic="twitter_topic"
client = KafkaClient("10.142.0.2:9092")
producer = SimpleProducer(client)
#producer = kafka.KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='10.128.0.2:9092')

def get_tweets():
    print("#########################get_tweets called################################")
    url = 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json'
    #query_data = [('language', 'en'), ('locations', '-130,-20,100,50'),('track' ,'#')]
    #query_data = [('language', 'en'), ('locations', '-3.7834,40.3735,-3.6233,40.4702'),('track','#')]
    query_data = [('language', 'en'), ('locations', '-3.7834,40.3735,-3.6233,40.4702'),('track','Madrid')]
    query_url = url + '?' + '&'.join([str(t[0]) + '=' + str(t[1]) for t in query_data])
    #print("Query url is", query_url)
    response = requests.get(query_url, auth=my_auth, stream=True)
    print(query_url, response)
    return response

def send_tweets_to_kafka(http_resp):
    print("########################send_tweets_to_kafka called#################################")
    for line in http_resp.iter_lines():
        print("reading tweets")
        try:
            full_tweet = json.loads(line)
            tweet_text = full_tweet['text']
            print("Tweet Text: " + tweet_text)
            print ("------------------------------------------")
            tweet_text = tweet_text + '\n'
            producer.send_messages(twitter_topic, tweet_text.encode())
            #producer.send(twitter_topic, tweet_text.encode())
            time.sleep(0.2)
        except:
            print("Error received")
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            print("Error: %s" % e)
    print("Done reading tweets")

##############
# Actual Execution starts here
###############
resp = get_tweets()
send_tweets_to_kafka(resp)
```

However, now I am trying to run this script inside a docker container, but it fails, and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_app.py", line 6, in <module>
    import kafka
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from kafka.producer import KafkaProducer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .simple import SimpleProducer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/simple.py", line 54
    return '<SimpleProducer batch=%s>' % self.async
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

For your reference, following are the contents of Dockerfile (Please note that, when I used the same Dockerfile with a simple script that was not using kafka, it worked perfectly fine):

```
FROM python:3
MAINTAINER kamal.nandan@<myemailservice>

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN pip install requests
RUN pip install requests_oauthlib
RUN pip install kafka

ADD twitter_app.py /
CMD python3 twitter_app.py
```

I have been fighting with it for the past few days, but I haven't been able to figure out the issue. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error occurs only in python 3.7, because of an incompatible change, [async is a reserved keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html) since this version.

The solution is to keep using python 3.6 until the library is adapted to the new version, there is an already closed [issue](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/1566):

```
FROM python:3.6
MAINTAINER kamal.nandan@<myemailservice>

RUN pip install requests requests_oauthlib kafka

ADD twitter_app.py /
CMD python3 twitter_app.py
```

(I took the liberty of reducing the Dockerfile)

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had the same issue: "invalid syntax" when importing kafka. It somehow worked for me when I substituted the following code:

```
FROM python:latest

RUN pip install docker
RUN pip install kafka
```

with this:

```
FROM python:latest

RUN pip install docker
RUN pip install kafka-python
```

This worked with no problem for python 3.7.4. I had pip 19.2.3, kafka-python 1.4.7.

Answer (score 1):

Use pip3 install kafka-python

then

import kafka