# Python Kafka SyntaxError while running a producer or a consumer

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm a newb to kafka and trying to create a simple hello world application using the link [tutorial](https://timber.io/blog/hello-world-in-kafka-using-python/). I got the zookeeper running followed by the kafka-server-start command, but when I execute the producer I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/consumer.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kafka import KafkaConsumer
  File "D:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\kafka\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from kafka.producer import KafkaProducer
  File "D:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\kafka\producer\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .simple import SimpleProducer
  File "D:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\kafka\producer\simple.py", line 54
    return '<SimpleProducer batch=%s>' % self.async
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried modifying the kafka-python version to 1.4.3, nothing seems to be working. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated
Following are my python files:
Producer.py:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
producer.send('sample', b'Hello, World!')
producer.send('sample', key=b'message-two', value=b'This is Kafka-Python')
```

Consumer.py:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer('sample')
for message in consumer:
    print (message)
```

The steps I followed are:
1. Initiate the zookeeper using the command

```
.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
```

2. After the zookeeper is initiated I executed the command

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

3. When the server was initiated I ran the command python producer.py followed by consumer.py

Could someone tell me where am I going wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your python version 3.6. there are some compatiblity issue with 3.7.

Check this [a python script fails to import kafka library while running inside docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52794786/a-python-script-fails-to-import-kafka-library-while-running-inside-docker)